# Uploading video to youtube from Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, youtube-javascript-api

Can someone help me out, i am trying to upload a video to youtube using nodejs(MEANSTACK). I am using the `youtube-uploader` module but this require me to install Python, i did but no luck.. this module has not been updated for a year.. can someone please help me with this out with a way to work around this or give me a module that work for this.. thanks in advance this is what have tired so far with the `youtube-uploader`

```
var youtubeUploader = require('youtube-uploader');

youtubeUploader.configure({
  accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,  // string
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,  // string
  clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,  // string
  expiresIn: EXPIRES_IN,  // string (default: '3600')
  idToken: ID_TOKEN,  // string
  refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,  // string
  tokenType: TOKEN_TYPE  // string (default: 'Bearer')
}, function (err) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err.message); }
  youtubeUploader.upload({
    path: VIDEO_PATH,  // string
    title: TITLE,  // string
    description: DESCRIPTION,  // string
    keywords: KEYWORDS,  // array of string
    category: CATEGORY_ID,  // string (refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list)
    privacy: PRIVACY  // 'public', 'private', or 'unlisted'
  }, function (err, videoId) {
    // ...
  });
});
```

And these are the errors am getting:

```
pythonPath = process.env.PYTHONPATH.split(':').concat(pythonModulesPath);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andela/workspace/jsworkspace/sportbay/node_modules/youtube-uploader/index.js:13:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Comment: You don't have `PYTHONPATH` in your environment variables

Comment: What output you get if you run `echo $PYTHONPATH` in your shell? (Or the equivalent for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in a terminal.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(which python)
```